# Repeat and concatenate a string N times

Tags: string, r, repeat

In Ruby I could repeat a String n times with the following:

E.G. `"my_string" * 2 -> "my_stringmy_string"`

Is there an equally simple way for doing this in R?

Answer (score 90):

You can use `replicate` or `rep`:

```
replicate(2, "my_string")
# [1] "my_string" "my_string"

rep("my_string", 2)
# [1] "my_string" "my_string"
```

`paste` will put it together:

```
paste(replicate(2, "my_string"), collapse = "")
# [1] "my_stringmy_string"
```

Answer (score 77):

With `R 3.3.0`, we can use `strrep` from `base R`

```
strrep("my_string",2)
#[1] "my_stringmy_string"
```

We can also pass a vector of values in `times`

```
strrep("my_string",1:3)
#[1] "my_string"                   "my_stringmy_string"         
#[3] "my_stringmy_stringmy_string"
```

Answer (score 21):

Use `stri_dup` function from `stringi` package

```
stri_dup("abc",3)
[1] "abcabcabc"
```

It is also vectorized, so you can do this:

```
> stri_dup(letters[1:3],4)
[1] "aaaa" "bbbb" "cccc"
```

Performance comparision :)

```
> microbenchmark(stri_dup("abc",3),paste(replicate(3, "abc"), collapse = ""))
Unit: microseconds
                                      expr    min     lq  median     uq     max neval
                        stri_dup("abc", 3)  2.362  3.456  7.0030  7.853  64.071   100
 paste(replicate(3, "abc"), collapse = "") 57.131 61.998 65.2165 68.017 200.626   100

> microbenchmark(stri_dup("abc",300),paste(replicate(300, "abc"), collapse = ""))
    Unit: microseconds
                                            expr     min       lq   median      uq     max neval
                            stri_dup("abc", 300)   6.441   7.6995  10.2990  13.757  45.784   100
     paste(replicate(300, "abc"), collapse = "") 390.137 419.7740 440.5345 460.042 573.975   100
```

Comment: I'm not able to detect the microseconds differences while I wait for my fingers to plan the next line I'm going to be typing, but +1 for the alternatives. I've seen this package before but haven't used it yet.

Comment: But if you have to use this function like 1000 times it makes a difference, doesn't it? :)

Answer (score 4):

The `stringr` library offers the function `str_dup()`:

```
str_dup("my_string", 2)

[1] "my_stringmy_string"
```

And it is vectorized over strings and times:

```
str_dup(c("A", "B", "C"), 2:4)

[1] "AA"   "BBB"  "CCCC"
```