# New column with character values based on row number

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe of linear regression results with 88 rows and 9 columns. Rows 1 to 44 are from unadjusted models and rows 45 to 88 are from adjusted models.

How can I add a new column called `Model` that takes character values of `Model 1` for rows `1:44` and `'Model 2` for rows `45:88`?

So far I have generated this column as follows but not sure how to edit the value to take `'Model 2`for rows `45-88`

```
results.all <- results.all %>% mutate(Model="Model 1")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359127/how-to-repeat-a-string-n-times-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
results.all$Model <- c(rep("Model 1", 44), rep("Model 2", 44))
```

or  (from the comments)

```
results.all$Model <- rep(c("Model 1", "Model 2"), each = 44)
```