# How to create a vector "a" by sampling that contains a character repeated n times in R?

Tags: r

That is it, I would like to know how to create a vector that repeats a character "n" times. Afterwards I'd like to concatenate those vectors. The end result would look somehow like this:

```
A A A A A A A... (100times)...B B B B B B B...(100 Times)...B
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat a String N times in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359127/how-to-repeat-a-string-n-times-in-r)

Comment: Look into `rep()`. For example, `rep(c("A","B"),each = 100)`