# Using print() function in R to print dashed lines (not in graphs)

Tags: python, r, printing

I can use `print(70*"_")`  in python to output dashed line as a separator between results.
Now how can I output the same results in R.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat a String N times in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359127/how-to-repeat-a-string-n-times-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

`strrep("_", 70)` this is just a base R function

`[1] "______________________________________________________________________"`

Answer (score 1):

```
print(paste(rep("_", 70), collapse = ""))
```

This works, but maybe there is a more elegant solution (it should also work without `print()`)