# how to create a vector of blank spaces of different sizes in R

Tags: r, string, whitespace, repeat, rep

I have a vector of "sizes" or "widths", like this one:

```
x <- c(1, 4, 6, 10)
```

and I would like to create another vector based on `x`, a vector like this one:

```
y <- c(" ", "    ", "      ", "          ")
```

Basically there are two imputs for creating `y`: the blank space `" "` and the vector `x`.

So as you can see, the vector `x` defines the length of the blank spaces in `y`. I know I can do this creating a function from scratch, but I'm guessing if there's some kind of function or combination with `rep`, `paste0` or other built in functions in R.

Any idea? thanks.

Comment: Related: [Repeat and concatenate a string N times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359127/repeat-and-concatenate-a-string-n-times)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `strrep`:

```
strrep(" ", c(1, 4, 6, 10))
#> [1] " "          "    "       "      "     "          "
```

---

In `stringr`, you can also use `str_dup`:

```
stringr::str_dup(" ", c(1, 4, 6, 10))
#> [1] " "          "    "       "      "     "          "
```

Comment: very nice solution, I didn't know this function, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```r
x <- c(1, 4, 6, 10)

sapply(x, \(y) paste0(rep(" ", y), collapse = ""))

#> [1] " "          "    "       "      "     "          "
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

```r
x <- c(1, 4, 6, 10)
y <- sapply(x, \(n) formatC(" ", width = n))
y
#> [1] " "          "    "       "      "     "          "
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(stringr)

x <- c(1, 4, 6, 10)

y <- str_pad(" ", width = x)

y
#> [1] " "          "    "       "      "     "          "
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>